# Libraries for decoding 3gp in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, decoding, 3gp

Does anyone know of any libraries or sdks for .Net that focus on decoding 3gp files into other media formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [FFLib.NET](http://www.intuitive.sk/fflib/) which is a wrapper for ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at Media Manager Pro:

http://www.all4dotnet.com/Products.aspx